# Почему не подргужаются классы через composer?

Tags: php, composer, autoload

Есть такая структура проекта:

```
common
    Component.php
web
    index.php
console.php
```

В composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "common\\": "/common",
}
```

В console.php:

```
<?php 
require _DIR_.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$component = new \common\Component();
$component->run(); // Все ок, класс подгрузился, работает.
```

В web/index.php

```
<?php 
require _DIR_.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$component = new \common\Component(); // Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'common\Component' not found in web/index.php on line 3
```

Если перенести index.php в корень, то все работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, если пути в composer.json начинаются со слэша, то в подпапках автолоадер работает не так, как я ожидал. 
Решение:

```
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
    "common\\": "common",
}
```